# why cannot insert data into sqlite?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

i got no idea why it return me nullpointerexception. I think is because the table don't have data. So, the data seem like did not add into database

this is my activity class.

```
private void createdata(){

    String title[] = {"rancangan1", "rancangan2", "rancangan3", "rancangan4", "rancangan5"};
    String date[] = {"isnin", "selasa", "rabu", "khamis", "jumaat"};
    String time[] = {"17:00-18:00", "18:00-19:00", "17:00-18:00", "18:00-19:00", "19:00-20:00"};
    String channel[] = {"astro ria", "astro ria", "astro ria", "astro ria", "astro ria"};
    try{
    for(int i = 0; i < title.length; i++){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE, title[i]);
        values.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_DATE, date[i]);
        values.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TIME, time[i]);
        values.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL, channel[i]);
        cr.insert(ImamShareData.DataContent.PROGRAM_URI, values);
            //Log.i(TAG, "Successfully added index " + i + " as ID " + mId[i]);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("error",""+e);
    }

}
private void filldata(){

    String[] from = new String[]{ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_DATE, ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TIME, ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL};
    String[] from1 = new String[]{ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.programdate, R.id.programtime, R.id.programchannel};
    int[] to1 = new int[]{R.id.programtitle};

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter SEL = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this, 
                    createGroupList(), R.layout.programgroup_row, from1, to1,       
                    createChildList(), R.layout.programchild_row, from, to);
    setListAdapter( SEL );
}
private List createGroupList() {
    String[] column = new String[]{ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE};
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    String title[] = null;
    for( int i = 1 ; i <= 5; ++i ) { 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ImamShareData.DataContent.PROGRAM_URI, column, null, null, null);    
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        title[i] = cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE));
        m.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE, title[i]); 
        result.add( m );
    } 
    return result;
}

private List createChildList() {
    String date;
    String time;
    String channel;
    String[] column = new String[]{ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_DATE, ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TIME, ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL};
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; ++i ) {
        ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
        for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n+=3 ) {
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ImamShareData.DataContent.PROGRAM_URI, column, null, null, null);
            HashMap child = new HashMap();
            date = cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_DATE));
            time = cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TIME));
            channel = cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL));
            child.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_DATE, date);
            child.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TIME, time);
            child.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL, channel);
            secList.add( child );
        }
        result.add( secList );
    }
    return result;
}
```

this is my contentprovider class

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialvalues) {
    TableNumber = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    if( TableNumber != PROGRAM){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    ContentValues values;
    if(initialvalues != null){
        values = new ContentValues(initialvalues);
    }else{
        values = new ContentValues();
    }

    SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = mDb.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_PROGRAM, null, values);
    if(rowId > 0){
        Uri programUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ImamShareData.DataContent.PROGRAM_URI, rowId);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(programUri, null);
        return programUri;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}
```

this is my datasharing class

```
public static final class DataContent implements BaseColumns{   

    public static final Uri PROGRAM_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + PROGRAMPATH);

    public static final String CONTENT_MORE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.android.imammuda";
    public static final String CONTENT_ONE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.android.imammuda";

    public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE = "ProgramTitle";
    public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_DATE = "ProgramDate";
    public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_TIME = "ProgramTime";
    public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL = "ProgramChannel";
}
```

this is my logcat

```
05-12 16:05:46.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5175): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:05:46.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5175):     at com.android.imammuda.Program.createGroupList(Program.java:112)
05-12 16:05:46.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5175):     at com.android.imammuda.Program.filldata(Program.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized your title variable in method createGroupList:

```
 String title[] = null;
```

...

```
title[i] = cursor.getColumnName....
```

in the for loop the length is hard coded to maximum 5, so the easiest fix is:

```
String[] title = new String[5];
```

Comment: ater i changed, i try to getstring(0), but it return me -1 mean column doest not exist. SO i try aother way which getcolumnindex but the column exist and return 0. i got no idea why like this

Comment: could you provide some code? Maybe it's easier to follow you then

Comment: `Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ImamShareData.DataContent.PROGRAM_URI, column, null, null, null); `
`m.put(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE, ""+cursor.getColumnIndex(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE)); `
it return me 0 because it first row. Then i use another function which is getstring()

`title[i] = cursor.getString(0);` or
`title[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImamShareData.DataContent.KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE)));`

it gave me arrayindexoutofbound because the result gave me -1 that mean it does not exist

Comment: Sorry haven't had time to look at it. Repost this part as a new question and get help from everyone instead of waiting on me